# Page callback for module admin settings not working

Tags: forms

Ok so it seems my callback for my admin settings is not working correctly. It keeps coming back with a HTTP Error 500 (Internal Server Error)

**Menu Hook**

```
function annotate_menu(){

 //Makes category
 $items['admin/config/annotate'] = array (
 'title' => 'Node Annotation',
 'description' => 'Adjust node annotation options',
 'position' => 'right',
 'weight' => -5,
 'page callback' => 'system_admin_menu_block_page', //function from system settings.
 'access arguments' => array('administer site configuration'), //who can see this.
 'file' => 'system.admin.inc', //file where callback function is called
 'file path' => drupal_get_path('module', 'system'), //get system module path
 );


 //Makes menu under category
 $items['admin/config/annotate/settings'] = array (
 'title' => 'Annotation Settings',
 'description' => 'Change how annotations behave',
 'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form', //function called
 'page arguments' => array('annotate_admin_settings'), //formID which is function name in annotate.admin.inc
 'access arguments' => array('administer site configuration'), //who can access settings
 'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
 'file' => 'annotate.admin.inc', //file where formID is located.
 );

 return $items;
 }
```

Page Callback

```
function annotate_admin_settings(){
//get array of node types with "internal names" as keys and "friend names" as values
//$options would return array('page' => 'Basic Page', 'article' => 'Articles');

$types = node_type_get_types(); //module function (node.module) that gets all node types and store in array $types

//go thru the $types array
foreach($types as $node_type){
    $options[$node_type->type] = $node_type->name; //access the $node_type object and store specific properties from the node_type object in $options array
}

$form['annotate_node_types'] = array(
    '#type' => 'checkboxes',
    '#title' => t('Users may annotate these content types'),
    '#options' => $options,
    '#default_value' => variable_get('annotate_node_types', array('page')), //when using the system_settings_form, the name of the form element must match the key of the variable_get ie $form[] = variable_get('$form[]', '')
    '#description' => t('A text field will be available on these content types to make user-specific notes.'),
);

$form['#submit'][] = 'annotate_admin_settings_submit';
return system_settings_form($form);

}

/**
process form settings submission
*/

function system_settings_form($form, $form_state){
    //loop thru each of the content type checkboxes shown on the form
    foreach($form_state['values']['annotate_node_types'] as $key => $value){
        //if the check box for a content type is unchecked look to see whether
        //this content type has the annotation field attached to it using the
        //field_info_instance function. if it does then we need to remove the
        //annotation field as the admin has unchecked the box.
        if(!value){
            $instance = field_info_instance('node', annotation, $key);
            if(!empty($instance)){
                field_delete_instance($instance);
                watchdog("Annotation", 'Deleted annotation field field from content type: %key', array('%key' => $key));
            }
        }else{
            //if the check box for a content type is checked, look to see whether
            //the field is associated with that content type. if not then add the
            //annotation field to the content type.
            $instance = field_info_instance('node', annotation, $key);
            if(empty($instance)){
                $instance = array(
                    'field_name' => 'annotation',
                    'entity_type' => 'node',
                    'bundle' => $key,
                    'label' => t('Annotation'),
                    'widget_type' => 'text_textarea_with_summary',
                    'settings' => array('display_summary' => TRUE),
                    'display' => array(
                        'default' => array(
                            'type' => 'text_default',
                        ),
                        'teaser' => array(
                            'type' => 'text_summary_or_trimmed',
                        ),
                    ),
                );
                $instance = field_create_instance($instance);
                watchdog('Annotation', 'Added annotation field to content type: %key', array('%key' => $key));  
            }
        }
    } //end forloop
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Change `function system_settings_form($form, $form_state)` to `function annotate_admin_settings_submit($form, $form_state)`.

Answer (score 0):

[system_settings_form()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.module/function/system_settings_form/7) is a function defined from Drupal, and you cannot define the same function twice. The function is defined in [system.module](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.module/7), which a module Drupal requires to work.

It is also the wrong name for the form submission handler, as your form builder contains the following line.

```
$form['#submit'][] = 'annotate_admin_settings_submit';
```

The form submission handler is then `annotate_admin_settings_submit()`, not `system_settings_form()`.